# I want to run a batch file present on my remote computer

Tags: java

I want to run a batch file present on my remote computer but I am getting an error that you don't have permission to access the share.

> errorcode--: 0x80070035 the network Path was not found

Please help me out

Thanks in advance

```
public class Remotly {

    public static void main(String arr[]) {
        String cmd;
        try {
            Process r = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \\\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\D:\\batch\\sas.bat");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Execution error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my remote system is password protected
 User name--::  YYY
Password--: bbb

Comment: does this work when you run this command manually in cmd ?? if not java tag is irrelevant

Comment: yes it works manually.

Comment: Dear 
Fast Snail can U plz help me out in this??

Comment: It works manually with a drive letter?

Answer (score 1):

The UNC path is incorrect, it contains a drive letter.

```
\\\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\D:\...
```

Instead, the folder must be shared by a name

```
\\\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\DriveD\...
```

To use it, you must map the network drive before, e.g. via

```
net use * \\\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\DriveD <Password> /User:<Username>
```

Comment: I have tried this but not did't get any output...



Process r = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \\\\XX.XX.XX.XX\\DriveD<XXX@1234> /User:<Administrator>:\\batch\\sas.bat");

Comment: Hello anyone is there to help me out 


Thanks In advance

Comment: @PankajDagar: You need to do it in two lines: `exec("net use...")` and `exec("cmd /c start ...")`.

Comment: Dear @Thomas,   



Do i use this????



c:\\windows\\system32\\net.exe use \\\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\DriveD<ABC@1234> /User:<Administrator>:\\batch\\sas.bat

Comment: I have also tried this but same result--:

String command= "net use D: \\\\10.50.10.46\\batch2\\sas.bat"+ "/user:Administrator hcl@1234";

Comment: @PankajDagar: you can only `net use` a directory, not the batch file. Please ask a colleague about basic understanding of Windows and network shares before starting programming it.